# Is there a way to make a hitbox ignore another one?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I was creating a multiplayer first-person medieval fighting game based on Skyrim and For Honor combat, with 3 different stances. In it, you can attack from 3 stances, and if the opponent is not holding the same stance, he takes the attack, otherwise he parries and the attacker takes a quick stun.
The problem starts when the Sword's Hitbox hits the player's own hitbox, causing unwanted results.

That's why I want to know if there is a way for making the player's sword ignore the collision with the player itself, so that he can't attack himself.

I also tried to put the method: Physics.IgnoreCollision(collider, selfCollider); Inside the OnTriggerEnter() function, Start() and Update(), and no solution worked.

```
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Enemy" || other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        //instant enemy combat
        CombatManager enemy = other.gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<CombatManager>();
        Debug.Log(enemy.currentStance);
        //If enemy stance is not the same of the attacker
        if(enemy.currentStance != this.currentStance)
        {
            //enemy is damaged
            //Get enemy LifeManager and subtract its health
            enemy.GetComponentInParent<LifeManager>().currentHealth -= swordDamage;
        }
        else
        {
            anim.SetTrigger("Parried");
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Startup` doesn't exist ^^ do you mean `Start` ?

Comment: Yes! Sorry, I mixed some things up 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
if(other.transform.root != transform.root)
{
    // NOT self collision
}
```

This basically checks if both objects belong to the same hierarchy. In other words if they have the same top-most GameObject or root.

Obviously I made some presumptions as to how your players avatars are rigged. Perhaps you will need to tweak this solution to suit your hierarchy.

Comment: That's why I said "Perhaps you will need to tweak this solution to suit your hierarchy." Method is good. Whether root is the parent object that can differentiate the hierarchies or if some other transform needs to be used is an implementation detail.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning the solution with compering rigid bodies assumes bones have one rigid body higher in the hierarchy. This may or may not be true. There are approaches to bones physics using separate rigid bodies for each bone for example. So this also may need to be adapted to the actual structure of the hierarchy.

Comment: that's two good points actually! :)

Comment: Man, that was incredibly helpful! I started to develop in unity not long ago and I had no idea that the root property even existed.